# Giving option to the user to activate airplane mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How to show an alert that will take user **(if clicked Yes)** to the settings app to change airplane mode settings.

From what i have researched one cannot activate/Deactivate airplane mode programmatically but is there a way to show an alert for user to activate airplane mode?**(like the ones that show if there are UIDeviceCapabilities keys in info.plist)**

Comment: why down vote..quite a valid question not asking a guide but an eligible way to ask user.(and i have also done my research before asking0

Comment: or a much simpler question..is there a way to show settings app form our own app..we can open a link in safari..call a phone..has apple made something for settings app?

Comment: http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/bring-airplane-mode-control-ba.html

Comment: yes..i saw that in a different question but someone suggested it is a private framework and apple won't accept it..any idea?

Comment: Cannot say. as I have not used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to show any alert for AirPlane mode..

Answer (score 0):

There is no apple approved way of launching the settings app at your will. However, if you include the key RequiresPersistentWifi in your info.plist and the network connection is unavailable, iOS will itself display a dialog for you which contains a button to launch Settings.

Comment: i know that..but apple won't accept the app since want i the user to switch between airplane modes. and asking that the app needs wifi will be an issue.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you specify wifi just for the airplane mode. As I did not know your reasons to launch the Settings app, I just mentioned a manner i which this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can use selenium network connection API on iOS.
Check this URL:
https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/network-connection/